# How to multiply two rows or columns?

Tags: octave

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [3, 2, 1];
c = a * b;
```

yields

> error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x3, op2 is 1x3)

Why can I not multiply these two rows of the same size?
I shouldn't have to run a for loop for this, but I don't know of another way...

I saw [section 1.2.3 here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-Examples.html), which indicates (to me at least) that I *should be able to do it*.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone would remove that down-vote.  This is not obvious stuff for someone who isn't savvy to matrix-based programming, nor should it be expected that I am going to have the correct terminology at hand.  I don't think my logic is faulty here, although it may be n00bish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see now that there is a [.* operator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Vectors_and_matrices). I did not know where to find that in the documentation, and it does what I want.

Comment: haha I love this site. I was looking for the same thing. The accepted answer is wrong and the correct answer is down voted. Good job StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

You made 2 rows, which can't be multiplied together.

The general form of matrix multiplication is "**Row-Dot-Column**", which means take the dot product of each row with each column. In your case you have 1 row, but 3 columns (which doesn't work!).

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [3, 2, 1];
c = a' * b;
```

> ans =
>
> ```
>  3     2     1
>  6     4     2
>  9     6     3
> ```

[image]

Comment: the ans I would have expected 'c' to yield is [3,4,3], an element-by-element multiply.